# How to determine the color of a shell script task in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, shell-script

There are various Ansible modules which can execute my own-written script (ansible.builtin.script, ansible.builtin.shell, ansible.builtin.command). However, I would like to determine the color of the task as usual:

- red if execution was not successful
- yellow on successful execution resulted a modification of the system
- and green if successed an no change was needed.

I think, it could be encoded most easily in the exit code of the script, but any other scriptable option is to me okay.

Unfortunately, all the relevant modules I have found until now, simply completely ignore the result.

What to do?

Comment: Note: Normally I use the builtin ansible modules for everything, here we can see an exception.

Comment: I think you are thinking about something like that : [Error handling](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html). Where you can specify when it should fail, change or be fine.

Answer (score 1):

> ***... it could be encoded most easily in the exit code of the script ...***

Right, the documentation about [Error handling in playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html) show how one [Define failure](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-failure) or [Define `changed`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-changed). This will work for `script`, `shell`, `command`, as well Custom Modules.

> ***... but any other scriptable option is to me okay.***

That is what the [`diy` callback – Customize the output](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/diy_callback.html) was made for. The [Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/diy_callback.html#examples) show how to implement and use it then.